# Carrying two laptops to India - will I have to pay duty?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items, import-taxes

I went to the U.S. on a business trip for 3 days. After reaching there, I purchased a laptop to do my business work. However, the very next day, my company provided me a new work laptop, and I had no idea that the company would provide me another laptop. Therefore, I have two laptops.

Upon my return to India, will I be allowed at the customs there to take both laptops or will I have to pay duty? I need to take both laptops and I won't be carrying the boxes in which the new laptops were provided.

Comment: With the caveat that we should never presume a user's reason for travels because of Rule 2 http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rule-2-dont-judge-peoples-motivations-for-traveling I do see you have three questions all related to how many X can I take back to India (laptops, Swiss watches, and iphones)... you know, as well as we, that a normal person needs but one phone, one watch, and usually one laptop, although a personal and a corporate laptop might be ok with normal customs officials. If I were that official, I would make you pay tax in all three cases...just saying.

Comment: To the Op: you seem to be extraordinarily able to afford the expensive items for yourself, more power to you. You also seem to know that taking these items back to India might cause you to have to pay taxes. Respectfully, I **strongly** recommend you read India's import laws yourself, and perhaps talk to a lawyer, if you can afford it. Asking a bunch of random relatively anonymous users on an Internet website for advice will be cold comfort if you run afoul the law because of that advice.

Comment: @CGCampbell- Definitely sir, i'll contact my lawyer on this  to avoid any trouble later . I would also like to point out that even after churning billion's in revenue every single fortune 500 company try to evade taxes , isn't that wrong but they still do it . Mostly everyone earning money tries to reduce their tax liability or even evade taxes altogether, isn't that wrong but they still do it . Now i would like to ask you are they all fools .Why shall i pay customs when i can simply avoid it without getting caught it isn't logical to pay taxes when you can avoid them ... just saying..

Comment: There is linked, in another of I believe your posts, a document from the government of India relating to what you can enter with. The answer to your question is: one laptop. If you bought yourself a second laptop, that is one too many. If you attempt to hide it, and are found out, you are a smuggler. If you declare it, and the customs dude is in a good mood and buys your story, he may let you through. If not, he may fine you. However, the answer is: one laptop is allowed. A second one: pay for it.

Comment: @mrinalharsh So basically you admit that you are not asking about the rules but trying to evade them. There is no point in starting a debate on Fortune 500 companies and what not, it's still the same and we do not entertain such questions.

Comment: You bought the laptop overseas, you have to pay the duty, I think it's quite simple. If you are looking for duty evasion techniques, you have asked a wrong question and probably on a wrong site.