# Easiest way to carry two laptops to India and back from USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india

I am traveling to India from US soon and I will be carrying with me a work laptop and my personal laptop.
I will be bringing both the laptops back to the States with me.

What is the easiest way to explain to customs in India (and US if required) that I'm not importing these items and avoid paying the customs fee?

Comment: Bring some documentation proving you bought them in India in the first place?

Comment: I didn't buy them in India. One is a work laptop and the other I bought in US. I was hoping I wouldn't have to pay duty fee if I'm not going to leave them in India.

Comment: Not sure whether you can avoid paying duty but it seems you are really importing them, at least temporarily, so you cannot very much “explain” that you aren't. How long will you stay in India?

Comment: That makes sense. I will be there for three weeks.

Comment: Hi Ashwin ... **purely** one person's experience.  Quite simply, customs at Mumbai are "not as bad as the rumours".  Again purely one man's anecdote ... I have arrived in Mumbai many, many times with **large amounts of** the most expensive laptops and other gear, and nothing was even mentioned.  By all means, your experience may vary.

Comment: Note that this question is a many times duplicate .... http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37041/carrying-two-laptops-to-india-will-i-have-to-pay-duty?rq=1 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/can-i-take-two-laptops-to-india-from-united-states-one-bought-in-india-and-one  BUT .. there is some confusion, as people tend to ask the various permutations  (I want to take laptops IN TO India, OUT OF India, THROUGH India, and so on.) I suggest you read through all the info here on this site, Ashwin!

Comment: Hi Relaxed - it's possible you misunderstood the question: I believe in this case, the OP is **from** the US, and will be **visiting** India.  (I believe, **but am not certain**, he just needs to bring something showing he bought them in the US: when leaving, show that.) What the OP is referring to: Indian customs are somewhat notorious about cracking down on people arriving with laptops ("as if for work") but in fact leaving them behind in India as gifts for friends.

Comment: In some countries it is possible to have potentially dutiable articles listed in a passport (or in a form to accompany a passport), to be checked at exit. Does this apply in India?

Comment: Hi all, just wanted to update everyone. I did end up taking two laptops with me, both in the the carryon. I wasn't stopped or asked any questions at any point and everything was pretty smooth. I did take a letter from my work just in case, but it wasn't needed. Thanks to everyone for their responses.